# Legitimate Universal Sets and Proof Check

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I noticed in my discrete math textbook that the Rosen makes reference to the universal set, denoted $U$, and establishes various results, like the complement of a set $A$ with respect to $U$, or the identity law $A \cap U = A$. But in what sense are we calling $U$ the universal set so that such a set is valid in elementary set theory? In other words, why is it legitimate in the author's case to speak of $U$ where it seems to be implied somehow that $U$ is not the set of all sets? Do I have to state that $U$ is specific universal set as to avoid confusion as to whether or not it is the set of all sets (but still calling the set $U$ rather than a concrete universe like $\mathbb{Z}$)?

With that question proposed, if we let $U$ be specific universal set (not the set of all sets), and define $\emptyset_1$ and $\emptyset_2$ to be two empty sets, then we can conclude that $\emptyset_1 = \emptyset_2$ by noting

$$U = {\emptyset_1}^c$$
$$U = {\emptyset_2}^c$$

implies that

$$U^c = ({\emptyset_1}^c)^c = \emptyset_1$$
$$U^c = ({\emptyset_2}^c)^c = \emptyset_2$$

Because $U^c = U^c$, then $\emptyset_1 = \emptyset_2$.

Of course, another way to do this proof would be to show that the two empty sets are subsets of each other.

Answer (score 1):

In those examples, we are working in the so-called "naive" set theory; in this case, the "universal" set is simply a collection of objects assumed as the *domain* where the variables range.

It can be the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers, or the set $Humanity$ of all human beings.

It is not intended to be the set of "everything".

With this approach, we can treat the elementary properties of sets : the so-called algebra of sets.

For example, if the domain (or *universe*) $U$ is the set $\mathbb N$ of naturals and $A$ is the set of *odd* numbers, then $A^c$ is the *complement* of $A$ "in $U$", i.e. the set of *even* numbers.

---

Regarding the "unicity" of $\emptyset$, this is straightforward.

We know that :

> for all $x$, $x \notin \emptyset$.

But we have also the [principle of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) for sets :

> if for all $x, x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B$, then $A=B$.

Applying it to $\emptyset_1$ and $\emptyset_2$, we clearly have :

> for all $x, x \in \emptyset_1 \leftrightarrow x \in \emptyset_2$

because both are empty.

Thus, we conclude with :

> > $\emptyset_1 = \emptyset_2$.

Comment: Ah, so proving that the two empty sets are subsets of each other demonstrates their equality. Definitely easier.

Just for hiccups and giggles, is the proof that I wrote valid?

Comment: @A.Lovelace - yes, it is.

Comment: thank you for your assistance, sir